# Get rows in chunks from huge tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get data from any table (table name is passed to procedure as parameter). I was trying cursor with bulk collect and it works very nice. However table name must be used as object only, not table name (varchar). How can I create type of table from table name? After selecting data by cursor they must be stored somewhere (in table which cannot be created as Above).

So, problem is with creating type of table from table name. Can you help me? Or maybe there is other/ better solution?

Edit ( I am adding code which was found on the net and change a little).

As you can see I am passing tableName parameter. I can invoke cursor using table name: OPEN c_data for 'select * from '||tableName; however I cannot create type from table name: TYPE t_bulk_collect_test_tab IS TABLE OF product%ROWTYPE;
In this (second example I am using table name not passed by parameter, called product). I would like to use here also parameter (tableName).

```
 create or replace procedure Procedure1 (limit_in IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 100, tableName in VARCHAR2)
as
begin

 DECLARE
  TYPE t_bulk_collect_test_tab IS TABLE OF product%ROWTYPE;

  l_tab    t_bulk_collect_test_tab;
c_data sys_refcursor;

BEGIN
  OPEN c_data for 'select * from '||tableName ;
  LOOP
      FETCH c_data
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT limit_in;
EXIT WHEN l_tab.count = 0;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_tab.count || 'rows');

  END LOOP
  CLOSE;
END;

exception
when others then
  raise;
end Procedure1;
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please show examples of what you are talking about.

Comment: It seems you are asking about Dynamic SQL. This is possible but is usually an indication of a bad design... You will have to provide much more information to get a helpful answer. Try to start with what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: I have just edited the post (code example and additional explanation).

Comment: What do you need to do with the fetched data? In your example you simply count the results, but how would you really use the results, without even knowing the structure ( name of columns, type, ...) ?

Comment: Yes, for now I am only counting the result. In next step I want to return result from procedure (this part is to do) and than write result to external file (XML) - in C# part. There are many tables in Db and it must be done autonomically, so I cannot write procedure for each table. It must work for all tables.

Comment: So maybe there are other solutions? Tables are really huge. I can't do simple SELET * FROM tableName because some tables have millions of records (some tables occupy e.g. 3 gb in disc space :) ).

Comment: Why can't you just open cursor in C# part and select chunks of data directly from tables? Why do you think stored procedure will do it better? Anyway you may consider dynamically creating stored procedure for every required table.

Comment: Konstantin, could you provide an example? I would really appreciate for even pseudo code or small part in sql.

Comment: Is question still actual? Could you clarify what example you need? I'm not sure but it seems you try to gen one chunk of data per one sql execution? In this particular case there are no general solution. But you can extract data from tables which have some ID by `select * from tablename where id between :a and :b`. If all you want is write results to external xml-file you may consider creating pl/sql procedure for this purpose.